# How to call a method of derived class from a method of base class without making it virtual?

Tags: c++

How would I do so without making base method virtual?

```
class Base {
public:
    bool foo() const;
}

class Derived : public Base{
public:
    bool foo() const;
}
```

Comment: Can you modify the base class at all? Then you might be interested in the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). But if you can modify the base class, it's easier to just make the function virtual to begin with.

Comment: `bool Base::isEmpty() const { Derived d; return d.isEmpty(); }`.

Comment: @juanchopanza I see you're going by "ask a silly question, get a silly answer" :-)

Comment: bigteeth, can you elaborate on *why* you need this? Currently, the question smells of an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need this, you can store a null pointer to a function with the foo's signature in your base class instances, and use the base implementation until this pointer is null. Then you can change this pointer in your derived class and associate is with your derived implementation. Then your base class can call that function via the pointer.

Below is some schematic code for this:

```
class Base {
public:
    bool foo() const {
        if (NULL == internalFoo) {
            // base implementation;
        } else {
           return internalFoo();
        }
    }

private:
    bool (*internalFoo)() = NULL;
}

class Derived : public Base{
public:
    bool foo() const;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, this strategy deserves a name! How about..."virtual function"?

Comment: This is just implementing a virtual function by hand.

Comment: @TonyK, of course it is. But if the case is just not using the 'virtual' keyword, but getting the same effect, why not ;)

Comment: The `Derived::foo` would have to be `static` to be able to get a normal pointer to it (perhaps taking the first parameter of `Base*` type and casting it internally to simulate `this`). With this change, this would be a good answer, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

There is no any sense to call isEmpty of a derived class from isEmpty of the base class because the base class knows nothing about its derived classes. Take into account that the base class is single while there can be numerous derived classes. So of what derived class are you going to call function isEmpty?

There is sense to call isEmpty of the base class in a derived class. it can be done the following way

```
bool Derived::isEmpty() const
{
   return Base::isEmpty();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. That's why there is a `virtual` keyword. If your class forbids use of this keyword, I'd rather not use it as a starting point to learn OOP.